# Prove $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax + b > 0 \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Prove
$$X := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax + b > 0 \}$$
is open.

Here $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m_{++}$ (only positive entries). Also, we have the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*My attempt:*

I know that I have to find a condition for $r$, such that $|| x - y || < r$ implies $y \in X$. For this I have considered $z = x + ty \in X$ which implies $Ax + rAy + b > 0$. Thus, $y \in X$ if $(-Ax) \geq (r - 1)Ay$. I could then try to take a norm on this inequality but this would  break the "if" direction. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $Ax+b\gt 0$ mean here? Does it mean "positive definite"?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I think it means every entry is positive.

Comment: @WhatsUp is right. It means that every entry is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear map is always continuous (for the usual topology).

In particular, the map $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ sending $x$ to $Ax + b$ is continuous.

Since the set $Y = \{y \in \Bbb R^m: y > 0\}$ is open, we see that $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ is open.

Comment: +1. I would add a hint for how to prove that $Y$ is open

Comment: @User It's the product of $m$ copies of $\Bbb R_{> 0}$, and we may use the fact that the usual topology on $\Bbb R^m$ is the product topology of $m$ copies of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: That or just put a point in it and draw a ball around it - basically equivalent

Comment: Thank you for the insight, WhatsUp! I actually had @rubikscube09's approach in mind, but that refreshed my mind :D :D

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that $x\mapsto Ax + b$ is a continuous mapping since $X$ is the pre-image of the set $\{y: y>0\}$ (I am guessing this means every entry is positive) that is open.

To prove that $x\mapsto Ax+b$ is continuous, would be enough to show that $\lVert Ax+b - Ay +b \rVert \leq C\lVert x-y\rVert$, since $x\mapsto Ax+b$ would be Lipschitz and therefore continuous.

In fact, if you define $C= \sup_{\lVert x\rVert = 1} Ax\leq D\max\{A_1e_1,\cdots, A_me_1,\cdots, A_me_n\}<\infty$, for some constant $D$.

Then $\lVert Ax+b - Ay +b \rVert= \lVert A(x-y) \rVert = \big\lVert A(\frac{x-y}{\lVert x-y\rVert})\lVert x-y\rVert \big\rVert\leq C\lVert x-y\rVert$